# Custom ListView Item Graphical Layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

Please forgive my ignorance, but this is my 3rd day with Android, and I've looked at tutorials, and they all seem to focus on the xml declaration of listview item UI. My question is this, I'd like to be able to see the custom listview item UI in the designer "Graphical Layout" in Eclipse. However, it displays it just like it does any other view in Android, ie. with the title and status bar at the top and taking up the entire screen. What I'd like to see is just the listview item that I'm designing ie. just 50dp tall and filled width. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have You tried to open your xml layout file for list item in Graphical Layout?

Comment: @sandrstar Yes I have and it shows the whole android screen, so the list view item kind of gets stretched to fit the screen, it works fine once you run it, but it makes designing it difficult, because you don't see an accurate representation of the design.

Comment: Basically, no way in current Android SDK even almost one year passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a custom adapter.
 What you are seeing is just the listview item, what you are looking for is the custom layout. Have a look at this tutorial, specifically the part on designing the custom layout and the custom adapter.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Comment: Yep, I've read that tutorial already, but like I stated it's more to do with the XML definition of the ListView Item. What I'm interested in is being able to see the "Graphical Layout" in Eclipse so that it just shows the list view item and not the whole screen.

Comment: You just click 'Graphical Layout' tab in the XML file. in the XML definition you can change the layout types height (i.e LinearLayout) to say 20dp and change the background colour and it will easily define it

Comment: Yeh, I tried that, I changed the height to 50dp and saved it, went back to graphical layout and it still shows the whole screen, top status bar and all... :(

Comment: if you dont want the status bar change the theme to full screen. but you cannot remove everything except for a 50dp high thing. The easiest way is just changing the background so youc an easily see

Comment: Ahh Ok, changing the background might be the way to go, I coming from an iOS background where you can define a custom view and it displays it without the status bar etc, I was hoping that eclipse had something similar. But thanks, your workaround will do the trick.

Comment: Nah XCODE is a walk in the park compared to Eclipse

Comment: Yep, I'm discovering that everyday :(

Answer (score 1):

It's a general Layout example to make custom listview :

Main Activity Layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

ListView Row layout XML (list.xml) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#CC0033"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#3399FF"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I stated in my original question, I'm not interested in the XML representation, I'm interested in the Graphical Layout.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to see what the listview will look like is to run the application on a device and fill the listview with test data. It's kind of a pain.