# Animate width of view from fill_parent to wrap_content?

Tags: java, android

I am looking animate a view I have. It is a listview item, so when it appears in the list it has the fill_parent value for the android:layout_width attribute. With this it fills the entire row of the listview. What I want to happen is once the item is added to the list, I would like for the layout_width to be animated to wrap_content value instead. I know that it could be done by me just changing the LayoutParams, but it would not be animated. A good reference of what I am talking about is in the Google Hangouts app. Once items are added to the conversation list, the item scales to wrap_content on the listview item. Does anyone know of a library or maybe something that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You only need is to make your own listview item layout and have one textview inside of it, then you can manage how the list item appears, see [`Android listview customization`](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html), [`Customizing list item throught ArrayAdapter`](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429), and [`Related Post about it`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506763/custom-listview-item-graphical-layout-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the layouts and at the same time animate it, but you can do this trick:
Your item layout must contain a `ViewSwitcher` inside of the `ViewSwitcher` put two childrens, two `RelativeLayout`, one with your item expanded view and the another with the collapsed view. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!- Change the in and out animation for some scale animation ->
    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/viewswitcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inAnimation="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        android:outAnimation="@android:anim/slide_out_right" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/expanded_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText_expanded"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="TextExpanded" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsed_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/editText_collapsed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:text="TextCollapsed" >
            </TextView>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ViewSwitcher>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I don't know when do you exactly want to perform the animation. You have two choices: One do the animation on the onFocus event. Two take your view instance and perform the animation with `post(someRunnable)`. If you choose the first one, the animation will be performed when the user scroll down and see the item, even if the item was added long time ago, but the item never won focus. If you choose the second option the animation (I pressume) will be performed when you add the new element, no matters if you are not actually seeing the item or not. I'm not pretty sure about this last one because the `getView` of the  `BaseAdapter` is executed in a lazy-way. Your adapter must be something like this:

```
    public class MyListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        List<String> model;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Boolean animated;

        public MyListViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity,
                List<String> modelArray, Boolean anim) {
            model = modelArray;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mainActivity);
            animated = anim;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return model.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return model.get(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return -1l;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View convertedView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertedView == null) {
                convertedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null, false);
            }
            TextView textCollapsed = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.editText_collapsed);
            TextView textExpanded = (TextView) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.editText_expanded);
            textCollapsed.setText(model.get(pos));
            textExpanded.setText(model.get(pos));
            final ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) convertedView.findViewById(R.id.viewswitcher);
            //First choice
            convertedView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (hasFocus) {
                        ViewSwitcher switcher2 = (ViewSwitcher) v.findViewById(R.id.viewswitcher);
                        switcher2.showPrevious();
                    }
                }
            })
            //Second choice
            switcher.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    switcher.showPrevious();
                }
            });
            return convertedView;
        }

    }
```

Well you had to play with this and see what happens. Sorry but I can't give you a 100% accurate answer. But I'm sure that this is the way to go. Hope it helps :]

BTW, pretty good question!